# PySpark: Iterate over values in PairRDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

How to iterate a value in RDD(key,value).

```
tsRDD.map(lambda x:(x,1)).groupByKey()
```

Returns

```
[('abc', <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0xb0e8242c>),
 ('pqr', <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0xb0e82a2c>),
 ('xyz', <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0xb0e824ac>)]
```

I want to iterate through the `<pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable` object and find its sum of all elements.

I tried

```
tsRDD.map(lambda x:(x,1))).countByKey().items()
```

which returns

```
`[('abc', 2), ('pqr', 1), ('xyz', 2)]`
```

But I need to use `.map` `.reduceByKey()` methods

Any ideas? or variations we can do?

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient thing you can do in this particular case is to use [`reduceByKey`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.reduceByKey) instead of `groupByKey`:

```
tsRDD.map(lambda x:(x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
```

In a general case when you have `PairwiseRDD` you can either `map`

```
# Python 2
someRDD.map(lambda (k, vs): do_something_with(vs))

# Python 3 
someRDD.map(lambda kvs: do_something_wit(kvs[1]))
```

or `mapValues`:

```
someRDD.mapValues(lambda vs: do_something_with(vs))
```